# Launch instance on service deployment

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs, autoscaling, aws-auto-scaling

I am using Terraform to deploy an ECS EC2 cluster on AWS.

My pipeline is creating a new task definition from docker-compose, then updates the service to use this task definition.
Desired count is 1, deployment_minimum_healthy_percent is 100 and deployment_maximum_percent          is 200.

Expected behavior is that the autoscaling group will launch a new EC2 instance to deploy the new task, then kill the old one.
What happens is that I get an error message : "service X was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. The closest matching container-instance has insufficient memory available."

No instance is created and the deployment is rolled back. How can I make sure that an extra instance is created when deploying my service ?

Here is my Terraform code :

```
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "main_cluster" {
  name        = var.application_name

  tags = {
    Environment = var.environment_name
  }
}

data "aws_ecs_task_definition" "main_td" {
  task_definition = var.application_name
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "main_service" {
  name            = var.application_name
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.main_cluster.id
  launch_type     = "EC2"
  scheduling_strategy = "REPLICA"
  task_definition = "${data.aws_ecs_task_definition.main_td.family}:${data.aws_ecs_task_definition.main_td.revision}"
  desired_count   = var.target_capacity
  deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = 100
  deployment_maximum_percent         = 200
  health_check_grace_period_seconds  = 10
  wait_for_steady_state = false
  force_new_deployment = true

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.main_tg.arn
    container_name   = var.container_name
    container_port   = var.container_port
  }

  ordered_placement_strategy {
    type = "binpack"
    field = "memory"
  }

  deployment_circuit_breaker {
    enable = true
    rollback = true
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [desired_count]
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = var.environment_name
  }
}
```

Auto-scaling group :

```
data "template_file" "user_data" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/user_data.sh")}"

  vars = {
    ecs_cluster = "${aws_ecs_cluster.main_cluster.name}"
  }
}

resource "aws_launch_configuration" "main_lc" {
  name          = var.application_name
  image_id      = var.ami_id
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  iam_instance_profile = "arn:aws:iam::812844034365:instance-profile/ecsInstanceRole"
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.main_sg.id}"]

  root_block_device {
    volume_size = "30"
    volume_type = "gp3"
  }

  user_data = "${data.template_file.user_data.rendered}"
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_policy" "main_asg_policy" {
  name                   = "${var.application_name}-cpu-scale-policy"
  policy_type            = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  autoscaling_group_name = aws_autoscaling_group.main_asg.name
  estimated_instance_warmup = 10

  target_tracking_configuration {
    predefined_metric_specification {
      predefined_metric_type = "ASGAverageCPUUtilization"
    }

    target_value = 40.0
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "main_asg" {
  name                 = var.application_name
  launch_configuration = aws_launch_configuration.main_lc.name
  min_size             = var.target_capacity
  max_size             = var.target_capacity * 2
  health_check_type    = "EC2"
  health_check_grace_period = 10
  default_cooldown     = 30
  desired_capacity     = var.target_capacity
  vpc_zone_identifier  = data.aws_subnet_ids.subnets.ids
  wait_for_capacity_timeout = "3m"

  instance_refresh {
    strategy = "Rolling"
    preferences {
      min_healthy_percentage = 100
    }
  }
}
```

Module is published here https://registry.terraform.io/modules/hboisgibault/ecs-cluster/aws/latest

Comment: Can you share you main module content? looks like there's some inputs that you need to set to the module to make it work, I'm curious about what values you put there

Comment: I added some code

Comment: Looking at the error message, it seems that your Task Definition needs more memory. have you tried bump the memory on task def to see if it goes through ?

Comment: My task is running on one instance with enough memory. When deploying a new task, it doesn't have enough memory so it should create a new instance but it doesn't. I don't want to increase the size of my instance to host two tasks because it would be a waste of resources.

Comment: @HenryBoisgibault Did you end up finding a solution to this problem? I'm facing the exact same one.